# Azure Application Gateway returns 502

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway, azure-aks

Our platform has an Azure Application Gateway configured with a number of back services hosted in an AKS cluster using the Azure Application Gateway ingress controller. One of the services is our core identity service eg https://login.mydomain.com. 
I can browse directly to this url and the login page is served fine. Due to having strict data sovereignty requirements, another service provides is a regional authentication service eg https://login-region.mydomain.com

We use an OIDC back channel flow to redirect the user from the global service to the relevant region to enter their user credentials. This also works correctly to authenticate the user. 
The issue arises when the regional identity server redirects back to the core identity service with the authentication token.

A `nginx 502 Bad Gateway` message is displayed.

As a side note, we have test environment configured that does not use Application Gateway, rather Kubernetes nginx Ingress controller for SSL Termination. During the configuration of this environment we had a similar issue and increasing the nginx proxy-buffer-size be increased 16k resolved the issue.

There is no limit set in the docs for Application Gateway: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/includes/application-gateway-limits.md

I'm not sure If I'm looking in the correct place or if this is completely unrelated.

Comment: Do you have a solution yet? Since I am also facing something similar.

Comment: @AbhirupGuha, No i didn't. I ended up deploying our global OIDC service in a standalone app service outside of Kubernetes which allowed us to get the service running.